# How to create a trust policy for an assumed role in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have two accounts, A and B. I also have two roles, X in account A, and Y in account B. I have a service in account A that assumes role X in account A and I need it to then assume the role Y in account B. The ARN of the assume role looks like this:

```
arn:aws:sts::<account A>:assumed-role/<some string>/<some string>
```

I want to add this ARN to the trust relationship of role Y in account B. This is what I've tried, but it tells me `invalid principal in policy`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::<account A>:assumed-role/*/*"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html), we cannot use wildcards in an assumed-role session principal.

> When you specify an assumed-role session in a Principal element, you cannot use a wildcard "*" to mean all sessions. Principals must always name a specific session.